# OpenForm freeze totally access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I use an access database to register some datas. I have a click_button to open a form which doesn't work anymore and before yes. When I click, access is blocked but I can yet tape in vba window, but everything in access is freezed and I can't run a code... The form is not showed at window, I think the access is blocked because the form is open but not showed... There is no code event in load or opening form.

I have tried to force with `Form.Visible=true` but it's not working...
I have tried with the extension acNormal `DoCmd.OpenForm "Insertion", acNormal` but it's not working...

I saw no properties button that can block like this...

```vb
Private Sub Commande250_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Insertion"
End Sub
```

Normaly, a window open with the form, on the principal window. The software is a principal form with button which open some sub form in the form, or other form. Just this form not open...

Comment: As a start, remove the `On error ..` line.

Comment: Sounds like the form is open but not yet centered. Try setting the autocenter = yes. also try setting the modal = no. you can also play with the left/width values to see if for some reason it is open but shrunken.

Comment: Show the code on the click_button that opens the form.